# Changing the order of init scripts.

Tags: debian, udev, init.d

I may sound stupid here, But how safe is it to change the order of the init scripts in debian OS?

Being specific here, there are these two **init.d** script files in the **/etc/rcS.d/** folder -

```
S02udev            --> I understand this script starts the udev framework

S10mountall.sh     --> I understand this script mounts all the storage devices
```

I also understand that this order (2 for udev) & (10 for mountall.sh) was set carefully by the OS developers and potentially a big impact exists in case I change it other way round.

**Background**

I have created a udev rule in Debian which runs a shell script when a USB storage device is plugged into the system.

The issue I am facing with this order is that, as the udev script is called first, my USB rule is created first, and the mountall script is called later, so any existing USB device (plugged in before system boot up) is mounted.

Therefore, udev treats even an existing plugged in USB as a new insertion event (during mountall) and processes the udev rule. This is exactly what I don't desire. I want the rule to work only for a new USB insertion event.

**Queries**

1. Is there a way to do achieve the above without changing the existing init script order??
2. If no, is it possible to change the init script order??
3. If yes, How?? and What is the system impact of changing this init script order??

Thanks,

Comment: But the mounting of the USB is a new insertion. (even if the drive has been in since last shutdown) since mounting the drive and inserting the drive (which then mounts) appear as similar systems events.
1. ?
2. Its not the script order that is causing the "problem"
3. Depends on the order.

You could list a known device in your fstab with `noauto` which would the device mounting on mountall.

You could leave a lock/mounted file on the device and when present not run the script. (which gets placed there after first running, you may need to update each boot or have some other "current" tracker)